# What is the eigenvalue of matrix from matrix minus all-ones matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

Suppose we know the eigenvalues of matrix A, and J is all-ones matrix with all elements are one. Then what are the eigenvalues of A-J?

ps. A is random matrix with element from distribution N(0,s)

Thanks.

Comment: I see. So how about the shift of eigenvalue's distribution of A? In other words, if we know the distribution of eigenvalues for A, then how about the distribution of eigenvalues for A-J? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Below was my answer to the question as it was originally posed. It has since been modified, and this is no longer a valid answer to the question.

There is no way that this question can be answered with the information given.

For example, 
$A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
$
has eigenvalues $1$ and $1$, and $A - J$ has eigenvalues $-1$ and $1$.

If 
$B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
$,
then $B$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$. However, $B - J$ has the eigenvalues $0$ and $0$.

Comment: Sorry for the inadequate information, if A is random matrix with element from distribution N(0,s), is there any way to know the shift of eigenvalues of A-J?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer to that question.